# Are glasses a barrier before erva for "Sh'ma"?

Tags: halacha, shema, see-sight-vision-blind

One cannot say "*Sh'ma*" facing someone undressed. Even if the prospective "*Sh'ma*" reciter closes his eyes, it's insufficient according to many. However, if the person is covered by clear clothing or behind glass, then closing the eyes is sufficent. *Mishna B'rura* [75:25](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=216).

Is "beyond the eyeglass lenses of the prospective reciter" as good as "covered by clear clothing or behind glass"? On the one hand, it's just another case of being behind glass. On the other, I've never heard of this leniency; and maybe the fact that the lens is specifically designed for seeing through, is frequently seen through, and abuts the reciter makes the presence more of a presence, or something. Anyone know of any sources (or strong arguments)?

Comment: The *Chayei Adam* (whom the *Mishna B'rura* is quoting) seems to only allow this (behind a window) for that which is not biblically considered *erva*.

Comment: If anything, I’d think the glasses would make it worse, since with them he can see the erva better than without, whereas by a clear clothing, it’s no more or less visible than without it.

Answer (score 5):

Berachot 25b

> אמר רבא צואה בעששית מותר לקרות ק"ש כנגדה ערוה בעששית אסור לקרות ק"ש כנגדה צואה בעששית מותר לקרות ק"ש כנגדה דצואה בכסוי תליא מילתא והא מיכסיא ערוה בעששית אסור לקרות קריאת שמע כנגדה (דברים כג) ולא יראה בך ערות דבר אמר רחמנא והא קמיתחזיא

For erva the issue is seeng, not covering.

Bet Yosef Orach Chayim 75 following his lecture in Rambam

> וכתב הרמב"ם דאסור לקרות כנגד הערוה עד שיחזיר פניו, משמע דבהחזרת פנים סגי אף על פי שהיא סמוכה לו, דהא לא תלה רחמנא ערוה אלא בראיה. ומהאי טעמא נראה שבלילה, או אם הוא סומא, או אם עוצם עיניו אפילו ביום, שרי

To orient your face in an other direction is alowed, Bet Yosef infered that even to close eyes following the Bet Yosef. Night or blindness or closing eyes are equivalent of changing direction. BY notes that this is against Rokeach (who follows Yerushalmi). He perhaps thinks that for erva seeng is the only issue, not Place.

BY opinion is also against the Rashba Brachot 25a who quotes Yerushalmi regarding erva (not covered by Ashashit), concerning night. The Rashba understand that blindness is an equivalent of night.

> וכדגרסינן בירושלמי רבי ליא וחבריא הוו יתבן קומי פונדקיא ברמשא אמרי רבי מהו מימר מילא דאורייתא אמר לון מכיון דאלו הוה ביממא הוי חמיין מה קומינן ברם כדון אסור. והוא הדין בסומא שאף על פי שאינו רואה מחמת מקרהו הרי הוא במקום שיכול לראות אילו לא היה מקרהו, שהרי כל אדם כסומין בלילה

Rashba also quotes Yerushalmi prohibits to read Shma in front of erva at night  or in a blindness state. It seems now that Rambam didn't agree with the apparent pshat of the Yerushalmi.

Bet Yosef can argue that the Yerushalmi thinks that for erva there is a din of "Machane", and we takes the opinion of the Bavli.

Bach

> ולא נהירא שהרי מפורש בירושלמי דבלילה אסור כיון שאם היה יום היה רואה ולפ"ז עוצם עיניו נמי אסור כיון שאם לא היה עוצם עיניו היה רואה הערוה לפניו דלא עדיף עוצם עיניו מבלילה וכ"כ הרוקח דאפילו יעצים עיניו אסור ומביאו ב"י ולא דמי להחזרת פנים דכשמחזיר פניו חשוב כאילו הערוה היא ברשות אחד והקורא שמע ברשות אחר שהרי עיניו פתוחות ואינו רואה אותה דמותר

The Bach makes a kind of shalom between Rambam and Yerushalmi (but this teruts is not valuable fo the extension of the din to closing eyes infered by Bet Yosef) that apparently contradict him. Bach makes a chiluk, to change head orientation because the body turned to an other side (machzir panav) is equivalent to changing place (the Taz is machmir to move the whole body, to turn the neck is not sufficient), far from the erva. But closing eyes or to become blind is not changing rapport to the erva  This is a new kind of changing place that remembers the din of tsoa, מחנים קדוש

Mishna Berura sk 29

> וכתב במשבצות זהב דאם הוא ברשות אחד ואדם ערום הוא ברשות אחר כנגדו והוא עוצם עיניו מלראותו י"ל דשרי בזה לכו"ע וכן משמע קצת בדרך החיים ובסימן ע"ט אות ח' באשל אברהם משמע דחזר מזה וכן בח"א כלל ד' אות ט' לא משמע כן אכן אם חלון של זכוכית מפסיק בינו לערוה ועוצם עיניו מלראותו מהני לכו"ע כיון דיש עכ"פ איזה חציצה המכסה נגד הערוה

For erva there is no din of "מחנך קדוש"  But The Bach extends it to erva.  We have a different concept of place.  Places you can not easily see Are different, not similar to the case of the Yerushalmi. In such a context, closing eyes is good enough even for the cholkim with Bet Yosef.

1. The source of this chidush is  a Gemara (25b) treating the case of a man immersed paritally in mikveh, up to the level of the abdomen. He can read Shema, despite the transparence of water. This makes the chiluk from the Yerushalmi quoted by rishonim (regarding erva in front of you, in your vision field). So, the chumra of the Yerushalmi regarding night or closing eyes is not relevant for Mike and for Ashashit.  **What is the similarity between the water of a mikveh in which the low part of the body is immersed and the Ashashit? This is the fact that they make a little not easy your gaze, and naturally, you are not watching in the direction of the water or the object inside the Ashashit. So, closing eyes is enough to allow KS. When there is no filters between eyes and erva, you have no difficulty to see it.**  **Glasses are made to improve vision, not to diminish your vision. Glasses facilitate your vision of the erva. Glasses are fixed in front of your eyes, you have no possibility to show things not through glasses.** (I find this in old notes on my Rashba. ). So the Yerushalmi is not a kashia.